# How would I go about solving this tricky problem involving the product and power rule?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

" $f(x) = x^{10}h(x)$

$h(-1) = 4$

$h'(-1) = 7$

Calculate $f'(-1)$."

I tried to do the power rule on the x^10 first and got 10x^9. However, I was not sure on how to proceed with h(x) using the product rule as it was not with usual x's and coefficients. And I am a little unsure on how to relate the 4 and 7 as the anti-derivative and derivative respectively to the question as a whole.

Any help?

Comment: Can you tell us what you got when calculating $f'$? Prior to evaluating at $-1$, I mean.

Comment: I couldn't quite get to that point because I am not sure how to differentiate h(x). And you need to differentiate h(x) to carry out the product rule.

Comment: Well, you can express $f'$ in terms of $f$, $h$ and $h'$, and then in particular when evaluating at $-1$, you do know the values for each function there. That's exactly why you're being required to use the product rule. Remember, just because you cant explicitly determine $h$, that doesn't mean you can't at least get a somewhat useful expression for $f'$.

Comment: I see. I should express it in terms of f. Now it makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$f'(x)=10x^9h(x)+x^{10}h'(x)$ (by product rule). So $f'(-1)=-10 h(-1)+h'(-1)=-40+7=-33$.